# VB.net stopping a backgroundworker

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I want to create a button that could stop my background worker and end all the process it is working on.

Here is my sample backgroundworker code:

```
       Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

            Try
                If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy <> True Then
                    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try

        End Sub

        Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

            Dim counter As Integer = 1

            Do

            'updated code with stop function----------------
            BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
            If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then
                e.Cancel = True
                ProgressBar1.Value = 0
                Exit Do
            End If
            'updated code with stop function----------------

            ListBox1.Items.Add(counter)

            ProgressBar1.Value = ((counter - 1) / limit) * 100
            counter = counter + 1
            Loop While(counter <= 999999999999999999)

        End Sub

        Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
            Try
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End Sub

        Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_Completed(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
            Try
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End Sub

        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False    
        End Sub

        'updated code with stop function----------------
        Private Sub StopButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StopButton.Click
              If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then

                  If BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation Then                
                     BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
                  End If
              End If
        End Sub
        'updated code with stop function----------------
```

I want to reset the loop and return the Progress Bar to 0% when i stop the backgroundworker.

Is this possible?

---

The code above has been updated and it is now working fine.

I have added this code inside my do loop:

```
        BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then
            e.Cancel = True
            ProgressBar1.Value = 0
            Exit Do
        End If
```

I created a button that stops the worker:

```
    Private Sub StopButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StopButton.Click
          If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then

              If BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation Then                
                 BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
              End If
          End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Backgroundworker class has the method `CancelAsync()` which you need to call to cancel the execution of the bgw.

You need to set the `Backgroundworker.WorkerSupportsCancellation` property to true and inside the while loop you need to check the `CancellationPending` property wether the value is `true` which indicates a call to the `CancelAsync()` method.

If `CancellationPending` evaluates to true, you would ( **which you should have done already** ) call one of the overloaded `ReportProgress()` ([Docu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx)) methods to set your ProgressBar value to the desired value.

EDIT: You should set the `Cancel` property of the `DoWorkEventArgs` to true so you can check the `Cancelled` property of the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` inside the `RunworkerCompleted`event.

You also shouldn not access any controls which lives in the UI thread. You better use the `ProgressChanged`([Docu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx)) event.

See: [BackgroundWorker Docu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress.aspx)

Comment: Thanks alot i have updated my original code with a working stop button. i have placed a comment between them saying "updated code with stop function"

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Class Form1
    Private iVal As Integer = 0
    Private Sub bgw_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgw.DoWork
        For iVal = iVal To 100 Step 1
            bgw.ReportProgress(iVal)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(99)
            If (bgw.CancellationPending = True) Then
                e.Cancel = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub bgw_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bgw.ProgressChanged
        pbar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
        lblProgrss.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() & "%"
    End Sub

    Private Sub bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgw.RunWorkerCompleted

        If (e.Cancelled = True) Then
            pic.Visible = False
            pbar.Value = iVal
            lblProgrss.Text = iVal & "%"
            btnstart.Text = "Start"
            btnstart.BackColor = Color.Green
        Else
            pic.Visible = False
            btnstart.Text = "Start"
            btnstart.BackColor = Color.Green
            iVal = 0
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnstart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnstart.Click
        If (btnstart.Text = "Start") Then
            btnstart.Text = "Stop"
            btnstart.BackColor = Color.Red
            pic.Visible = True
            bgw.RunWorkerAsync()
        Else
            If (bgw.IsBusy = True) Then
                btnstart.Text = "Start"
                btnstart.BackColor = Color.Green
                bgw.CancelAsync()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```